# Removing view from superview iOS

Tags: ios, animation, delegates, viewcontroller

I am struggling with understanding why the first method below works for hiding and removing a subview of a view.  In this first method I pass the pointer by reference.  In the second method, which is less general, I have a delegate method designed for removing a specific view.  I would like to use the first method, because I have several views that I would like to apply this too.  I should mention that the first method works without fail as long as it is called within the implementing class.  It fails when I call it from the view controller that I wish to dismiss.  I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the removeFromSuperview line when it fails in the first method.

```
-(void)closeView:(UIViewController **)viewController
{
 [UIView transitionWithView:self.view 
                   duration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^
  {
   [[*viewController view] setAlpha:0.0];
  }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
  {   
   [[*viewController view] removeFromSuperview];
   [*viewController release], *viewController = nil;
  }];
}

-(void)closeButtonClicked
{
 [delegate closeView:&self];
}

//
// This method works without fail:
//

-(void)closeView
{
 [UIView transitionWithView:self.view 
                   duration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^
  {
   // In this context viewController is defined in the class interface
   [[viewController view] setAlpha:0.0];
  }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
  {      
   [[viewController view] removeFromSuperview];
   [viewController release], viewController = nil;       
  }];
}

-(void)closeButtonClicked
{
 [delegate closeView];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is not according to the style guides, and not a good idea in general, to do a release of the viewController within a method like this. It will get you into trouble quickly. If the caller of this method is responsible for the viewController (it has done the retain), then it should release it as well. This is likely the cause of the first method not working from within the viewcontroller itself.

In the second method you do not pass in the viewController as parameter, which means it needs to be defined in the context.

If you don't release the viewController in this method, then you don't need to set its variable to nil either, and you can simply pass it as normal parameter:

```
-(void)closeView:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
 [UIView transitionWithView:self.view 
                   duration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                 animations:^
  {
    [[viewController view] removeFromSuperview];
  }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

you would then do this at the call-site:

```
[self closeView:childViewController];
[childViewController release]; childViewController = nil;
```

It safe to release the child in this way before the animation is done, because the animations block implicitly retains all objects referenced from the block, including the viewController parameter. Therefore, the child's dealloc is not called until the animations block releases it.
This does not work in your first code example, because you pass a pointer to a variable. That is, the animations block does not know it needs to retain the child.

BTW, I am not sure why you want to set the alpha, in the example above I show that you can also remove the view already in the animations block. See more about that in the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW112).

Comment: Thank you for the advice about not needing the alpha.  This is good news.  Let me explain my reasoning a bit more so you understand why I want to release the view that is being removed.  I am doing this to decouple the handling of the action from the child view that is being displayed.  I would like the parent view to decide what to do with the child.  I do not want the default action of this action to be to remove and nullify the child view.  With that being said, I don't see why it is problematic for a parent to remove a child from the view and nullify it. Could you explain :)

Comment: Just as an added comment, the removefromsuperview did not animate in the block.  I still had to put it in the completion block with the alpha in animations for this to work as desired.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @PatrickHogan Sorry about that, I should have adapted your code properly. For the options: parameter you need to choose one of the UIViewAnimationOptionTransition options, in order for the animation to apply to the removed view. CrossDissolve is probably the one you would want. I will adapt the code to show that.

Comment: @PatrickHogan Regarding the release: There is nothing wrong for a parent to remove a child from the view, and you do just that with the removeFromSuperView. But it is very confusing to pass the address of a variable to somebody else and ask it to release and nullify it for you. In fact, that is likely where the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error comes from: you forgot that the closeView is now responsible for the release, and also release it in another place while the animation is running (maybe the dealloc of the parent?). The "[*viewController view]" then references an object that is already released.

Comment: Thanks for the update on the transition.  Also, I have placed a breakpoint in the dealloc of the child view and it is not called until the completion block is executed.  The completion block is there so that cleanup does not occur until the animation is complete.  I have to pass the address so that I can set it to nil.  If I pass just the pointer and release it everything works fine.  I am still a bit confused as to why this is not working in this case, but I think I am going to chalk it up to an unseen typo or logic error until I find more evidence.  Thanks for your followup :)

Comment: That behaviour is only natural. In my code, the animation block does a retain on all objects referenced in the block, including the viewController parameter. Therefore, you can safely release the child from the parent right after you call closeView, if needed. The dealloc of the child is called after both the parent, and the animation block references are released. In your first code example, that is different. Because you pass in a pointer to a variable, the animation block cannot do a retain on the child. Therefore, releasing the child in the parent will lead to the crash you have noticed.

Comment: Great explanation!  I understand why this is happening now.

Answer (score 0):

**viewcontroller and &self is not the way to go. In Objective-C, you do `[self.view removeFromSuperview]` in the subview itself, in the parent viewcontroller you do `release` or with ARC just replace the subview with another view.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I left a detailed comment above explaining my position.  Could you clarify yours in the context of what was written :) ?